# Comparison operator in count() is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

```
SELECT 15 > 14 FROM Duel;
```

This code snippet is working in MySql but not in SQL Server:

> SQL Error(102): Incorrect syntax near '>'

I have a requirement where I want to see if at least 1 record exist return 1 or else 0

```
SELECT count(emp.name) > 0
FROM ****
WHERE *** IN (***)
```

Check the db fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=348709a562ad02cbe88abf01a37229f1

Comment: You can use IF EXISTS instead of getting count and comparing with 0

Comment: This one I ended up using
SELECT IIF(count(erm.employee_code) > 0, 1, 0)
FROM ****
WHERE *** IN (***)

Comment: "Duel"? no, it probably isn't working in MySQL.

Comment: random table name I wanted to menton

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `having`

```
 SELECT 1 from new_table_name
   having count(empName)>0
```

**Update**

You can use `SIGN()`. It returns `1` when result is positive and `0` when the result is `0`

```
SELECT SIGN(COUNT(*)) FROM new_table_name
```

[**Check fiddle here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6d6bba365094e9b714457c9f729a1b30)

Comment: You would still need to account for the "else 0" part of the question. If the predicate is not met result set is empty.

Comment: @JorgeGarcia , Ah! i didn't notice the `else` part. Updated the more simpler form

Answer (score 1):

Try `case` statement -

```
select case when count(emp.name) > 0 then 1 else 0 end
from ****
where *** IN (***)
```

Comment: case is working, I though I can do in 1 line without ccase

Answer (score 1):

You can try EXISTS clause

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 emp.name
        FROM ****
        WHERE *** IN (***))
BEGIN
    SELECT 1
END
ELSE
    SELECT 0
END
```

As you want to return either 1 or 0, you need to define the values in CASE statement.

```
select case when exists(SELECT emp.name
            FROM ****
            WHERE *** IN (***)) then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use COUNT. You don't want to count the rows, just to see if there is one. And don't use logic like IF, just use CASE.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM **** WHERE **** IN (****)) 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a CTE like this:

```
WITH T (C)
AS  
-- Select the first record with a value in emp.name
(  
    SELECT TOP 1 1
    FROM **** emp
    WHERE *** IN (***)
    AND emp.name IS NOT NULL
)
-- just count the elements of T
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM T
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3514827fadaf6b8d19c2658008df0a99

---

If you prefer the one-line solution without having to COUNT all records, here is an alternative:

```
SELECT IIF(exists(select TOP 1 1 from **** emp where emp.name IS NOT NULL), 1, 0)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=be6c753a6ddb164524576061c3b8802e

Answer (score 0):

All answer provided by is working fine. But SQL Server already provides comparison function.

```
SELECT IIF(count(erm.employee_code) > 0, 1, 0) 
FROM **** 
WHERE *** IN (***)
```